# Which strategy is best for this simple probabilistic game...

Tags: probability, statistics

The game is as follows:

There is a infinitely large bag of balls; half of them red and half of them black.

You initially draw N balls at random and the objective is to end up with all balls of one colour, and to do this you are allowed to swap/replace balls from the N you have with other balls from the bag. The two different paths/strategies you are can take from this point are either:

1. You are allowed to replace ALL (only all of them, not a subset) balls with another randomly selected set of N balls. You are allowed to repeat this up to R times (R will also be the number of times you are allowed to make replacements if you choose option 2) and if at any point all N balls are the same colour you win and the game stops.
2. You are allowed to only replace a subset of size n (n < N) of your set of N balls, where n remains constant throughout the game and again you are allowed to make a subset replacement up to R times. The subset of n balls is chosen randomly from your existing N balls at each replacement iteration and the game stops if all balls achieve the same colour.

My intuition is that strategy 1 will have the maximum likelihood of achieving a full set of the same colour, can someone please explain if this is true and if so why? I would be interested to know what the relationship is between the probability of achieving a full set and the ratio of n and N..

Comment: Replacing $n=N-1$ of the balls has the same odds as replacing all $N$.

Comment: Your description of the problem is rather unclear. I think "infinitely large bag of balls" should mean that you have a bag with infinitely many balls. You say "half of them red and half of them black". What should this mean? It makes nos sense to speak of the half of an infinite set. You wrote "draw N balls at random". I think you want to say that you draw the balls with equal probability for all balls. It is known that this is not possible and also makes  not sense.

Comment: What I think you want to write instead of drawing N balls form ininitely many balls is that you have a bag with one white and one black ball. You draw one. You have equal probability to draw a black  or a white. This makes sense for a finite number of balls. The probability is 1/2 for each ball. You note the color of the ball and put it back into the back and repeat this N times.  Please update your post appropriate

Answer (score 1):

I think strategy 1 is better. Let's make it simple and assume that $N=3$.

Strategy 1 has probability $1/4$ for success in each draw, so the expected
number of draws (including the initial) until success is $4$ with this
strategy.

In strategy 2 we only replace one random ball in each draw. The expected
number of draws is then a bit trickier to calculate. Let's denote the
expected number of draws by $x$. There is a $1/4$ chance that we succed on
the first draw. Given that we do not succed on the first draw, we know that
we will have $2$ of one colour and $1$ of the other. Denote the conditional
expected number of additional draws we need by $x_{21}$. Then note that $%
x_{21}=\frac{1}{6}(1)+\frac{5}{6}(x_{21}+1)$, i.e. we have $1/6$ chance to
succed on the second try (we must first draw the right ball for replacement
and then draw the right colour on the new ball, hence $\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2}%
=\frac{1}{6}$) and $5/6$ chance to stay in the $2,1$-state (either the
initial or the mirrored state, which is the same by symmetry). We can solve
the equation for $x_{21}$ according to $x_{21}=6$.  Hence $x=\frac{1}{4}(1)+%
\frac{3}{4}(6+1)=11/2$.

Hence, the first strategy is the best. I am not competent enough to prove
this in the general case, but I think the relative advantage of the first
strategy will get bigger and bigger when $N$ increases.